# Getting days between two dates with IQueryable

Tags: c#, date, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable query which I need to use sometimes in the same method.
This query is based on another one which is passed as parameter.

I need to sum the result of a value multiplied by the number of days between two dates.

parameter query =  IQueryable lista;

```
IQueryable<ChildEntity> query = lista.SelectMany(s => s.ChildEntities).Where(w=>w.IsActive.Equals("Y");

DateTime maxDate = lista.Max(m => m.Date);

decimal value = query.Sum(s => (s.Value) * (maxDate - s.ParentEntity.Date).Days);
```

which gives the exception:

```
Specified method is not supported.
```

I've also tried:

```
decimal value = query.Sum(s => (s.Value) *  SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(maxDate, s.Parent.Date);
```

tried also **SqlFunctions.DateDiff** and **EntityFunctions.DiffDays** and all of these last three gives me this exception:

```
Method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] 
DateDiffDay(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' 
is not supported for execution as SQL.
```

I do not want to use Enumerable because this can result in a huge number of records.

Is there any other way to find a solution for this?

(by the way, I'm using Devart as provider.)

Comment: the IEnumerable  isn't your problem as IEnumerable like IQueryable is only evaluated on instantiation, as long as you remove the Max date variable this doesn't happen ie DateTime maxDate = lista.Max(m => m.Date);

Comment: as long as you don't read the list all it will do is pass the list definition into the query builder

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the database you are running the query on doesn't have a time-span data type like net does, however most databases store a date as number of days since a official start date, this means that if you convert the dates to a number you can just do straight arithmetic on it

```
days = ((int)maxdate) - ((int)currentdate)
```

NOTE:thats sudo not runnable

Answer (score 0):

```
int days = 0;
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime maxDate = lista.Max(m => m.Date);

While (today <= maxDate)
{
   today.AddDays(7);
   days++
}
```